# Delete row, setting foreign key references to other

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I frequently want to do a sort of 'merge' on table `a`, which is referenced by `b` like:

```sql
UPDATE b SET a=1 WHERE a=2;
DELETE FROM a WHERE id=2;
```

'merging' `a`'s row `id=2` into `id=1`, *updating* the foreign key(s) pointing at it, rather than cascading the delete.

---

Clarification: `1` & `2` is just an example, it might be on a given occasion that `(3 & 6)`, `(10 & 27)`, and `(10 & 42)` need to be 'merged'. And then another day there might be more.

---

It's a bit of a pain, especially when there are multiple tables with foreign keys into `a`. Is there a more convenient way of handling this? I'm imagining something such as:

```sql
--PSEUDOCODE NOT VALID SQL
DELETE FROM a WHERE id=2 ON FKVIOLATION SET fk=1;
```

Comment: Is there any logic behind updating the value of a from 2 to 1 or just manually you are choosing this

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I can't think of a time that it hasn't been a manual choice, but a method that could work with programmatic values too would be ideal of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is. You can set a default value for the foreign key, and use `ON CASCADE SET DEFAULT` in your FK constraint.

Using your example, where `b.a` is a foreign key referencing `a.id`, and you want to set orphaned FKs to 1:

```
ALTER TABLE b ALTER a SET DEFAULT 1;
ALTER TABLE b DROP CONSTRAINT fk_whatever,
ALTER TABLE b ADD FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES id ON CASCADE SET DEFAULT;
```

This will set orphan foreign keys to whatever default value is set for the foreign key. The only way it wouldn't work is if you were already using a different default value for something else.

Comment: If I have to alter `b` (and every other `c`, `d`, et al. that have a foreign key to `a`) isn't this more work than my current `update b` (`c`, `d`, et al.) solution?

Comment: Sure it is. Once. :) Once you alter the tables this way (and you can write them as a script and run it), then you can skip line 1 in your problem statement forever after. You talked about cascading deletes; you'd have to do something similar to this if you wanted to set that up. Same idea in terms of setup, but with the behavior you want: instead of cascading deletes, set the keys in the records that would be cascade deleted to a default value.

Comment: Ah, my question wasn't sufficiently clear then, I've (hopefully) clarified it. This is something I'd do multiple times, for different data. For example, where I wrote `1` & `2`, it might be (`3` & `6`), (`10` & `27`), and (`10` & `42`) that need to be 'merged'.

Comment: @OJFord Oh, that makes more sense. You had me scratching my head a bit there! :) If you don't always need the same value, you'd have to do something else. I would suggest that you investigate stored procedures.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea, why didn't I think of that.. thanks!

Comment: Sure enough. It would probably be a simple one.